# Spring data JPA clone entity with LAZY relationships

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GUID", nullable = false)
    private String guid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Person> persons;
```

And I need clone this entity. I do it like this:

```
usersRepository.detach(user);
```

But I can not get `roles` and `persons` becaus it `LAZY`. I use hack:

```
    user.getRoles().size();
    user.getPersons().size();
    usersRepository.detach(user);
```

But I do not like it. Can I make it easier?